# extract results from html using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have looked all over this and other forums and have been banging my head on how to do this.

I have a geolocation script that uses `document.getElementById("zip").innerHTML = data.zip;`) to display the results into the innerhtml of something like this:

`<p id="zip"></p>`
NOTE: This html is all that's needed to get the results to show.

The final html results are `<p id="zip">12345</p>`.
NOTE: This is what shows after the results are inserted by javascript above.

I would like to know how to set "12345" (from the example above) to a php string:
`$zip = 12345;`

and completely remove `<p id="zip"></p>` from the page.

I have used str_replace to try to pull out all of the html and leave the zip, but have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you're trying to pass data from javascript to PHP?

Comment: Use `strip_tags` instead of `str_replace`.

Comment: How are you sending the value to PHP in the first place?  By "have had no luck" do you mean that you're successfully sending the string to PHP and are unable to remove the HTML tags from it, or are you not successfully sending the string to PHP at all?  Please provide more information regarding the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: @Chris Herbert - Yes, essentially, I would prefer to pass the data from javascript to php somehow to allow me to use the data to assign to `$zip` and use it as such:
`<? echo $zip;?>` 
in several places on the page.

Comment: @stealthyninja - I tried your method and it didn't work.

Here is what I tried exactly:
`<? $text="<p id='zip' class='il'></p>";?>
 <? $stripped_text=strip_tags($text);?>
 <? echo $stripped_text;?>`

Comment: @David - I can successfully get javascript to populate the data into the innerhtml, but I have had no luck trying to get php to recognize that there is data there in order to strip the tags from the final result...
For example, I get `<p id="zip"></p>` to give the result of `<p id="zip">12345</p>`, but when I use `<? $text="<p id='zip' class='il'></p>";?> <? $stripped_text=strip_tags($text);?> <? echo $stripped_text;?>` to pull out tags, I get a blank result. 
However, if I `echo $zip;` I get `<p id='zip' class='il'></p>`, as expected.

Comment: If you're just going to be echoing the value and not actually doing anything with it that needs to be done on the server side, don't use PHP for this.

Comment: @noitalever: Well, PHP has no way of examining the state of the DOM.  In order to post information back to the server, that information needs to be included in the request, such as a form value or part of a POST request body.

Comment: @David - That makes sense. I guess I need to figure out the bast way to do that. Looks like `<input type='hidden' id='zip' value=''></input>` might be my best bet, huh?

Comment: @noitalever: If it's a simple POST request (particularly if it's a page-level request and not AJAX) then most likely, yes.  You could potentially do some trickier things with a POST body in an AJAX request, but shouldn't unless you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just use a hidden field?

`<input type='hidden' name='zip' value='12345'>`

then if isset post['zip']

you get the picture

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try that now and see if I can't get it to send the data to the server using:
`<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['form'].submit()
  }
</script>`

and add <form action="post.php" name="form"> to see if I can get the data to send on pageload.

I'll let you know how it pans out.

Comment: I ended up creating a form with all geo info populated into hidden select options, and js that submitted on timer, hid all html except for a div that had a splash so that when people arrive to the site they see that instead of the form. After 5 seconds, it submits the form data to the database, then redirects header to the main site, which uses the collected geo form data to provide a geo-location specific experience.

@David - Your reminder that PHP cannot read the DOM and the suggestion given by user2879041 gave me exactly what I needed to get this project working properly.

Comment: Auto submitting a standard form is pretty disruptive, since it will reload the page.  Seems like a perfect time to use AJAX.